# Android Studios App crashes when pressing .- combination

Tags: android, android-studio

I developed a simple app, and it works like it does, but on my phone the Samsung Galaxy a71 is a false keyboard which destroys my app. (Example in the Image). Can you help me with it, I don't want to code an extra keyboard just for the app. In the picture below, you can see the combination of signs which causing the error. I didn't found a way to change the keyboard specific on apps. In my opinion, the error occurs while the double input of a . or a - is a UTF formation that can't be controlled by parsing it to double.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the crash log in the Android Studio IDE? The `log` will give you crash reasons in detail.